# Filter post by year (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, date, filtering

I would like to filter news by year.

For ex. `| 2017 | 2016 | 2015 | 2014 |`

After click the date it displays all post from the selected year.

I try to use this source code:

```
<?php
query_posts(array('nopaging' => 1, ));
$prev_year = null;
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
      $this_year = get_the_date('Y');
      if ($prev_year != $this_year) {
          if (!is_null($prev_year)) {
             echo '</ul>';
          }
          echo '<h3>' . $this_year . '</h3>';
          echo '<ul>';
      }
      echo '<li>';
      echo '</li>';
      $prev_year = $this_year;
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
  ?>
```

I have a problem with right linking to year; how to add a `href` attribute to link the years?

Comment: still your not explain your problem

Comment: How to add a href attribute to link the years?